# Assigning range of numbers to a letter in python

Tags: python, string-formatting, nested-lists

Is it possible to assign range of numbers to a letter in python, without getting into the loop, I am trying to print a row of numbers separated by pipe,these rows will be the index of a list contents so it depends on the length of the list,so if the length of the list was (4) the output would look like this:

---

### |     |       0 |       1 |       2 |       3 |

I can't use a for loop sice it will keep printing everything so:

> length=len(list)
>
> for i in range (length):
>
> ```
> print (("|","%5s"%("|"),"%7d"%(i))
> ```

#### I can't do this since it will print everything over

I was thinking about something without going the loop it's self ,some letter to save the set of numbers, so maybe I am asking about something like this(i know it's not possible this way but,something similar maybe?):

> i in range (length)

and then loop only the "i" value using a while loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `end` argument of `print` to control the line end behavior. Setting `end` to an empty string will remove the default newline; that way, multiple `print` statements can write on a single line.

Example:

```
print('| ', end='')
for i in range(4):
    print(str(i) + ' | ', end='')
```

Output:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
print("|" + "|".join([str(ind) for ind,ele in enumerate(l)]) + "|")
|0|1|2|3|
```

`ind` will be the index of each element in the list, just `str.join` the contents separated by a pipe  and concat a pipe either end.

Or use range and map:

```
print("|" + "|".join(map(str,range(len(l)))) + "|")
```